# How to clear editor.scene before loading a new file?

Tags: three.js

Working in editor, loading a new geometry, I am trying to query the scene and remove existing geometries. The editor.scene.children and editor.scene.__webglObjects are both undefined. If I console.log( editor.scene ); and expand the object the children and __webglObjects have the elements I am trying to access. My clicker fingers are getting worn out trying to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Placing a

```
function deleteOnLoad(){
    editor.storage.init( function () {

        editor.config.clear();
        editor.storage.clear( function () {
        } );

    });
}

deleteOnLoad();
```

before the main editor.storage.init seems to be one way to handle this.